# When will Radon Nikodym derivative equals zero

Tags: measure-theory, radon-nikodym

Let $\mathcal{P}$ and $\mathcal{Q}$ be two $\sigma$-finite measures on the measure space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$. Let $\mathcal{Q}$ be absolutely continuous with respect to $\mathcal{P}$, that is, for every measurable set $A$, if $\mathcal{P}(A)=0$, then $\mathcal{Q}(A)=0$. According to the Radon-Nikodym theorem, there exists a nonnegative Borel function $f$ such that $\mathcal{Q}(A) = \int_A f \,\text d\mathcal{P}$ for all $A \in \mathcal{F}$. Then, this function $f$ is the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $\mathcal{Q}$ with respect to $\mathcal{P}$ and is denoted by $d\mathcal{Q}/d\mathcal{P}$.

**My questions are:**
i) When will $f=0$?
ii) If $\mathcal{P}(A)=\mathcal{Q}(A)=0$, does that implies $f=0$? Or $f$ is an arbitrary number since we have $0/0$?

Comment: i) just when $P(\Omega )=0$, ii) $f$ is arbitrary in sets of measure zero (respect to $P$). iii) $Q$ must be also $\sigma $-finite to apply the Radon-Nikodym theorem

Comment: @Masacroso Thank you! I will also update in my question about $\mathcal{Q}$

Comment: sorry, in my previous comment I meant $Q(\Omega )=0$ instead

Comment: If $\mathcal{Q}(\Omega)=0$ and $\mathcal{P}\ll\mathcal{Q}$, then $\mathrm{d}\mathcal{P}/\mathrm{d}\mathcal{Q}=0$ holds $\mathcal{Q}$-almost everywhere. However, this does not mean that $\mathrm{d}\mathcal{P}/\mathrm{d}\mathcal{Q}$ is a zero function. In fact, *every* measurable function on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ is equal to the zero function $\mathcal{Q}$-a.e., and so, *any* non-negative measurable function can be the Radon–Nikodym derivative.